# iPhone ridiculous memory leaks

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uiwebview, overhead

I have been stuck on the problem of memory leaks in my iphone app for a good time now. I feel like I have to be reading my data wrong. it seems like whenever I allocate memory in there is so much overhead that is causing leaks that when I release the data my memory usage either barely drops or does not drop at all. One have wasted 2 days on is my UIWebview on my flipside view controller loads a url and the memory usage of my app jumps from 3 mb to 7. I release the webview in my dealloc method but the huge block of memory is still living. Does anybody have any suggestions.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];

nav_bar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width+20,45)];
[self.view addSubview:nav_bar];
[UINavigationBar release];

rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done)];
item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Flipside View"];
item.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
item.hidesBackButton = YES;
[nav_bar pushNavigationItem:item animated:NO];
[rightButton release];
[item release];

NSAutoreleasePool *initPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

web_view = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,45,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height - 45)];

web_view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
web_view.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);

NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.tutorialpark.com/wpcontent/uploads/3/HeartBlending.jpg";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[web_view loadRequest:requestObj];
[self.view addSubview:web_view];
[web_view release];
[initPool release];

[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)dealloc {
   [nav_bar removeFromSuperview];
   [web_view removeFromSuperview];
   [rightButton release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

I apologize about the indentation I am very pissed off right now and don't want to deal with it.

Comment: Btw i am seeing these leaks in both the simulator and the real device

Answer (score 2):

You seems to be confused about how the reference counting works.

See comments below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];

  UINavigationBar* nav_bar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width+20,45)];
  // nav_bar retaincount 1
  [self.view addSubview:nav_bar];
  // nav_bar retaincount 2
  [nav_bar release];
  // nav_bar retaincount 1 - now controlled by self.view

  UIBarButtonItem* rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done)];
  // rightButton retaincount 1

  UINavigationItem* item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Flipside View"];
  // item retaincount 1

  item.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
  // rightButton retaincount 2

  [rightButton release];
  // rightButton retaincount 1 - now controlled by item

  item.hidesBackButton = YES;
  [nav_bar pushNavigationItem:item animated:NO];
  // item retaincount 2

  [item release];
  // item retaincount 1 - now controlled by nav_bar

  UIWebView* web_view = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,45,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height - 45)];
  // web_view retaincount 1

  web_view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
  web_view.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);

  NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.tutorialpark.com/wpcontent/uploads/3/HeartBlending.jpg";

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
  // url is autoreleased, you can ignore..

  NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  // requestObj is autoreleased, you can ignore..

  [web_view loadRequest:requestObj];

  [self.view addSubview:web_view];
  // web_view retaincount 2

  [web_view release];
  // web_view retaincount 1 - now controlled by self.view

  [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)dealloc {
   // don't need to do anything because all the memory is controlled by self.view, will be released when the internal variable self.view is released.
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: thanks that definately cleared up some things for me but the data loaded by the webview still exists after I dismiss the filpside view. Its nice because it doesn't have to reload the url but i want it to no longer be cached in the memory. Is there a way to release the data loaded into the webview i would think that would be done by the webview deallocating but according to my handy allocations graph it is not.

Comment: It is better to think of retain counts as a delta;  you add and subtract the retain count.  In the above, the comments are quite likely incorrect-- the retain count may be 2, it may be 5, it may be 492, the important thing is that *it doesn't matter*.  You should *only* worry about the retains you cause.

Comment: it's true that the count may be anything, but it was more meant to be a rough mental guide to where the count would change and where roughly transfer of owership occurs.

Comment: A quick search turns up that UIWevView may infact be leaking memory: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UIWebView+memory+leak

Answer (score 1):

[UINavigationBar release]; - What is this doing? Is it meant to be [nav_bar release] ? - If so it should be done later as slightly further down the code you access nav_bar again. But then it seems to be a member variable? So it should be released in dealloc.

rightButton is being released twice - Once in viewDidLoad and once in dealloc.

Can you please explain what the auto release pool is for?

Comment: the autorelease pool is left over from an old piece of code I must have glanced over it when I posted